# Декодирование "I" Frame h264 в изображение

Tags: изображения, видео

Работаю с видеопотоком на уровне сокета - распаковываю RTP заголовки и упаковываю в требуемые форматы контейнера, поэтому с h264 кодеком знаком не по наслышке.

Недавно встала задача научиться декодировать "I" Frame для получения из него сырой картинки. (как известно, I Frame содержит полную информацию об опорном кадре, в отличие от B и P кадров). Поэтому уверен, что задача стоит только в грамотной интерпретации заголовков фрейма.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным? В ITU h.264 Recommendations об этом сказало очень мало и размыто.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию по данному вопросу.

Comment: 1. Скачайте спецификацию на h264. 2. Возьмите извесную библиотеку ffmpeg - выкачайте и разбирайте. И... задайте вопрос с опорой на спецификацию либо на ffmpeg, либо на другую извесную библиотеку (в итернете две либы гуглятся на h264), указав источник.

Comment: Спецификацию нашел не помню как, по словам из неё "draft isd/iec 14496-10" вот документ http://ip.hhi.de/imagecom_G1/assets/pdfs/JVT-E022d7ncm.pdf возможно он ответит на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Так же, можно перехватить через F12 пакеты в хроме или фоксе, сохранить, и преобразовав с base64 в байты - проиграть в универсальном плеере а так же разобрать на байты и найти нужную инфу на конкретных байтах. В любом случае нужна конкретика.